# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error / Oracle service doesn't start

Tags: oracle

After having dropped a few tablespaces with the `removing contents and datafiles` options on a `Windows` machine, I noticed the `datafiles` were still there.
So I tried to delete manually the `datafiles`, but I was warned that the files were in use. I then shut down (`shutdown immediate`) the instance and deleted the datafiles manually.
Now the instance does not start (I suppose it's looking for the missing datafiles).
I'm trying to connect to sqlplus

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

but I get the error

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

I restarted the machine and the `Oracle Service` doesn't start (`the listener is up`).

What can I do?

I think I should put the `datafiles offline` and `drop` them, but I cannot connect.

Comment: do you remember the names of tablespaces. Are you sure of type they're non-system. By the way, contents may be related to system type tablespaces, even if they're of type non-system. Don't you have a whole backup?

Comment: I do remember tablespaces names and datafiles (I also find info about deletion in the alert log file). I do not have a backup, this is a local machine for developing purposes.

Comment: is there any tablespace of undo or temp type among dropped ones?

Comment: no, only regular permanent tablespaces I created